# Oracle find and update a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of multiple records and i want to find and update the duplicate record id from the table:[image]

I want to update the id "16" to 19 or 100 by the description column.

```
 select * FROM table1
  WHERE description = 'Online Portal'
```

By this i can find the duplicate values

```
  update table set id = 21 where description = 'Online Portal' ;
```

By this it update both the record's id but i want only one to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work by finding the min rowid.

```
update table T set id = 21 where description = 'Online Portal' AND ROWID > (SELECT MIN(ROWID) FROM TABLE X WHERE X.DESCRIPTION = T.DESCRIPTION);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
        update table1 set id = 21 where ROWIDTOCHAR(rowid) =
        (
          select ROWIDTOCHAR(rowid) rid  from table1 
          WHERE description = 'Online Portal' and rownum = 1
         )
```